# useMutation get Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render in React+Vite

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vite

When I reload the website with 1 component containing:

```js
const MyHotels = () => {
  const {showToast} = useAppContext();

  const {data: hotelData, refetch} = useQuery(
    'fetchMyHotels',
    apiClient.fetchMyHotels,
    {
      onSuccess: () => {}
    }
  );
  const {mutate: hotelBlock} = useMutation(apiClient.hotelBlock, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      showToast({message: 'Change complete!', type: 'SUCCESS'});
      refetch();
    },
    onError: (error: Error) => {
      showToast({message: error.message, type: 'ERROR'});
    }
  });

  const {mutate: hotelDelete} = useMutation(apiClient.hotelDelete, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      showToast({message: 'Delete complete!', type: 'SUCCESS'});
      refetch();
    },
    onError: (error: Error) => {
      showToast({message: error.message, type: 'ERROR'});
    }
  });
  const handleBlock = (hotelId: string) => {
    hotelBlock({hotelId});
  };
  const handleDelete = (hotelId: string) => {
    hotelDelete({hotelId});
  };
return (
<div>
   {hotelData.map((hotel, index) => (
     <>
      <div
         onClick={() => handleDelete(hotel._id)}
         className='cursor-pointer flex bg-blue-600 text-white text-xl 
         font-bold p-2 hover:bg-blue-500'
      >
         Delete
      </div>
      <div
         onClick={() => handleBlock(hotel._id)}
         className='cursor-pointer flex bg-blue-600 text-white text-xl 
         font-bold p-2 hover:bg-blue-500'
      >
         {hotel.block ? 'Blocked' : 'Open'}
      </div>
     </>
    ))}
</div>
);
};
```

It will create errors: Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. and do not display any data on the screen. But when I saved again in this code to reload the component, it would not have the error of uncaught Error: Rendered More Hooks Than During The Previous Render. So this error only appears whenever I reload page and I have checked, I see that if I leave a mutate processing, it will not have an error when loading the page.

I see I have created 2 mutates with different names but it only really does not have a fault when only one mutate in 1 component. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Seems *somewhere* you are conditionally calling a React hook or something that calls a React hook. Can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese A short version provided by me. help me please